# Chrome and Safari issues with map area coordinates dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, imagemap

I really need to generate the coordinates for an image map area through javascript. For some reason Chrome and Safari fail to map it properly. This is my code in a simple way:

```
dynamicMapping('#targetMap', [360,288,470,180,880,180,980,288]);

function dynamicMapping(targetMap, coordinates){

    var coords = '';

    for(i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++){
    coords += (coordinates[i]+',');     
    }

    $(targetMap).attr("coords", coords);
}
```

The coordinates are supposed to draw a trapezoid, which works great on Firefox but it fails to draw the first point on Chrome and Safari. If I enter the coordinates in the HTML, everything works perfect but form reason going through javascript makes Webkit miss the first point of the coords which results in a triangle instead of a trapezoid. Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `coordinates.join(', ')` to join the elements into a comma-delimited list. It might even fix your code.

Comment: @Blender Yes, that fixed my code, although without the extra space after the comma just (','). Can you please post this as the answer so that I can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is probably not parsing your `coords` string correctly. Your code returns `1, 2, 3,`, but Chrome expects `1, 2, 3`.

Try using `Array.join()` to construct the attribute's value:

```
$('#targetMap').attr('coords', [360,288,470,180,880,180,980,288].join(', '));
```